# Prometheus Grafana Templating order by count

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to put a dropdown for each API end point which will show the QPS and Latency of http requests (RED metrics).

I used Grafana's templating and used the following prometheus query.

```
label_values(http_duration_milliseconds_count, api_path)
```

But the problem here is sort order. It shows some longtail api requests like /admin/phpMyAdmin all.

I want to do only the top 10 endpoints by count to be shown in this drop down. How do I achieve this?

Attached an image for reference on my first dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

We can use **query_result** to achieve this.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-query-variables

```
query_result(topk(10, sort_desc(sum(http_tt_ms_count) by (api_path))))
```

***http_tt_ms_count*** - is my metric timeseries of Prometheus with time taken.

***api_path*** - is my label name

This query_result will give three-tuple value like this.

```
{api_path="/search/query"} 25704195 1507641522000
```

used the **Regex** field in query path to get only the api names.

```
*api_path="(.*)".*
```

This looks like a long way but

```
label_values((topk(10, sort_desc(sum(http_tt_ms_count) by (api_path)))), api_path)
```

is not working in Grafana which made me to go into this path.